# Cannot launch a app with Chrome extension with forge (trigger.io)

Tags: trigger.io, forge

I have created the app with forge, and have added in the chrome extension, but when i run with chrome, always show the following errors:

```
Currently it is not possible to launch a Chrome extension via this interface.
The required steps are:

    1) Go to chrome:extensions in the Chrome browser
    2) Make sure "developer mode" is on (top right corner)')
    3) Use "Load unpacked extension" and browse to D:\mobile-app\test/development/chrome
```

but I really done with above steps, I don't know what happen.

and I want to know how can I use difference Android sdk and resolution simulator with testing?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome doesn't a way for us to automatically install browser extensions. Therefore, you have to install your extension manually.

To do that, in Chrome (see image below):

1. type chrome:extensions in the address bar
2. turn on developer mode
3. click Load unpacked extension

[image: how to install Chrome extensions]

If you have a separate question about Android SDKs, probably best to ask that in a different thread, or contact support@trigger.io.

Comment: OK - how does it not work? Do you get an error message? Does the extension install but not work properly?

Comment: when I open chrome, there is no anything happen with the app, but if I add a button in the config.json and use the popup button to launch the app, it's work, but when I launch with the froge IDE tool or with command line "forge run chrome" then will occure the above error and cannot launch anything

Comment: OK, so if you add a button the app works as expected? There's no problem with the actual app itself? We have no way to automatically install / launch Chrome extensions: it's expected that you need to install the app manually, then reload it when you make changes. http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/tutorials/facenote/tutorial-1.html#building-the-app

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, using:

```
forge run chrome
```

to try to run the app in the Chrome web browser. I thought the 3 steps given were to install an extension which would then allow `forge run chrome` to launch the web application. I couldn't understand why, after installing the extension (with no button defined of course), nothing seemed to change. I didn't realise a Chrome extension version of my app, appearing on the toolbar, was even possible!

I should have used:

```
forge run web
```

to launch the app in the (default) browser.